# GVariantBuilder build a(ii) or a(vv)

Tags: c, glib, gvariant

I have this array of 2 int's I want to sent over dbus.
It always complains that value is not of type tuple or null
depending on the attempt. Hwow does it need to look like?

```
    GVariantBuilder builder;
    g_variant_builder_init(&builder, G_VARIANT_TYPE("a(ii)"));
    g_variant_builder_add(&builder, "(ii)", 99, 99);
    g_variant_builder_add(&builder, "(ii)", 98, 98);
    GVariant *value = g_variant_new("a(ii)", &builder);
    g_dbus_method_invocation_return_value(invocation, value));

    //g_dbus_method_invocation_return_value(invocation, &value)); - also tried

     //Previous attempts
    //GVariantBuilder *builder; 
    // builder = g_variant_builder_new(G_VARIANT_TYPE("a(ii)"));
    //g_variant_builder_add(&builder, "(ii)", 99, 99);
    //g_variant_builder_add(&builder, "(ii)", 98, 98);
    //and
    //g_variant_builder_add(builder, "(ii)", 99, 99);
   //g_variant_builder_add(builder, "(ii)", 98, 98);
```

Answer (score 4):

`GVariantBuilder` is not meant to be used as the payload for a `GVariant`: it's a [builder pattern object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), which will construct the `GVariant` from its contents:

```c
GVariantBuilder builder;

// Initialize the GVariantBuilder with the final type
g_variant_builder_init (&builder, G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a(ii)"));

// Add the contents of the variant
g_variant_builder_add (&builder, "(ii)", 99, 99);
g_variant_builder_add (&builder, "(ii)", 98, 98);

// Construct the variant from the builder
GVariant *v = g_variant_builder_end (&builder);
```

You should see the documentation for [`g_variant_builder_init()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariant.html#g-variant-builder-init) and [`g_variant_builder_end()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariant.html#g-variant-builder-end) for more information.